# How to set badge with FCM v1 http api

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a react-native application using Firebase to handle push notifications. I always used FCM legacy api to send the notifications.

I recently switched to the new FCM v1 API. After changing authentification mode and payload structure, everything is working well, except the badge count on the app. I checked the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages, there is a `notification_count`field for Android, but nothing for iOS. With the legacy api, I was able to define a `badge` property.

Here is my current structure :

```
'message' => [
    // Android
    'android' => [
        'priority' => 'HIGH',
        'notification' => [
            'notification_count' => $badge
        ]
    ],
    // iOS
    'apns' => [
        'payload' => [
            'aps' => [
                'notification_count' => $badge
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'token' => $deviceToken,
    'notification' => [
        'title' => $title,
        'body'  => $body
    ],
    'data' => [
        'title'   => $title,
        'message' => $body
    ],
    'fcm_options' => [
        'analytics_label' => $analyticsLabel
    ]
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

The solution was finally to replace `notification_count` by `badge` under '`apns`' => '`payload`' => '`aps`'